# Trust Certificate for Local Site Served by Virtual Machine

Tags: iis, browser, certificate, parallels

### My Setup

- I have a MacBook Pro with Parallels installed running a Windows 10 VM.
- The Windows 10 VM is hosting a local website via IIS.
- The site has a proper certificate configured. I can open a browser in the Windows VM, enter "localhost", and the browser recognizes the site as "secure".
  [image]
- When I hit the VM's site from a browser on my Mac (using the name of the machine), the certificate is not trusted and I am prompted to acknowledge this and continue.
  [image]
- My bindings look like this in IIS on the VM.
  [image][image]

Any ideas on how I can configure this to show as trusted on my Mac's browsers?

Comment: Unless you buy a valid certificate from CA (or Let's Encrypt), you only only force Safari to accept the certificate, https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/making-ssl-certificates-trusted-in-safari-1910.html Other web browsers have similar configuration.

Comment: I've tried this in Chrome and it shows as a trusted certificate in Keychain Access. However, navigating to the site still causes the "Not Secure" warning and requires you to manually proceed.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0 Chrome checks for more.

Comment: @LexLi, I am not following. I have created a certificate as shown in the link you provided and it works on the browser in the VM. However, it does not work when I access the site from a browser on my Mac.